# How to get an Interface in Kotlin from Android SDK with reflection and use it?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to use an interface from the Android Camera class that is not exported in the SDK. It is setup like this

```
//interface defined as
public interface Camera$CameraMetaDataCallback {
    void onCameraMetaData(byte[] data, Camera camera);
};

//set callback defined
class Camera {
    ...
    public final void setMetadataCb(CameraMetaDataCallback cb)
    {
        mCameraMetaDataCallback = cb;
        native_setMetadataCb(cb!=null);
    }
    ...
}
```

I can get the interface class I am assuming with

```
val CameraMetaDataCallback = Class.forName("Camera\$CameraMetaDataCallback").kotlin
```

and the method with

```
val CameraSetMetadataCb = Camera::class.java.getMethod("setMetadataCb", CameraMetaDataCallback.java)
```

but how do I actually use the interface object and set a callback?

Comment: I'd highly recommend you don't do this, unless you totally control the hardware it runs on, and are willing to drop the feature/rewrite it completely for future versions of the OS.  Private interfaces are private, they can rewrite them at any time, including for just a patch release.  And unlike the public SDK, they won't maintain any sort of backwards compatibility or deprecation if they do-  it will just go from working to crashing.

Comment: @GabeSechan agreed, we build the android images ourselves for a specific device (and in 
 fact specific camera). However rather then setup the changes needed to open the API in the SDK and provide a custom SDK for Android Studio I would rather check if I can pull it via reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use `cameraSetMetadataCb.invloke(objectToCallItOn, param1, param2, param3, ...)`  That calls the method referred to by the cameraSetMetadataCb object using objectToCallOn as the this pointer and passes the given parameters.  But as I mentioned in comments above-  you really don't want to do this, unless you have total control over the hardware it runs on.  Any change, even a minor patch, to the OS can change this function's signature or remove it entirely and break your app.

Comment: I am a C++ developer hacking something through to Kotlin, so my Kotlin understanding is limited. How would the interface be used, normally you would just inherit from it and override the methods. How do you do that at runtime, or is it enough for the "override" function to just have the same type definition and not actually inherit from the interface (again coming from a strictly typed language)

Comment: THe code you posted gets a Method object-  a reference to a method.  The code I posted causes it to call that method on a particular object.  You wouldn't be overriding an interface, you'd be calling an implementation to it that you wouldn't normally have access to.

Now to do this, you need the instance of the object in the first place.  If you can't get that, you can't call it, even by reflection.  Instance methods need an instance to be called on.

Comment: I understand that but the 1st parameter of `setMetadataCb` is an interface class, which I have the type of at runtime. How do I create a `CameraMetaDataCallback` instance with an overridden `onCameraMetaData` function?